# Can't figure our how to do simple theme for ".sh" files. Is there a DocForDummies?

Tags: aptana

I installed the Aptana Studio 305 plugin into my pretty-new Eclipse install.

I've been looking for a really complete light theme, that includes colorization for bash, sh, etc scripts as well as the usual PHP, CSS, HTML, JS, etc that I need.

I didn't find one, so I geuss I gotta create some of my own.

I'm completely mystefied how I edit a theme.

I see the Aptana->Theme preferences, but how do I create a set of colors/highlights/etc to use, for example, for ".sh" files?

Is there a aptana-themes-for-dummies doc somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Install the [ShellEd - Eclipse Shell Script Editor](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/shelled/). It works with Aptana Studio and allows you to customize the theme preferences for ".sh" files.